# Parsing a CSV file with a header line

Tags: perl, csv

I have a CSV file with a header line that I am required to use Perl to parse with the environment I am in.

The incoming CSV file has the following format (Header with data separated at each line):

```
Short_Description,Priority,Status,Office_Location,E-mail,Contact_Type,Service_Level,Campus,Ticket_Priority,Region,Country,School,First_Seen,Detection_Method,Description,Assignees 
Patch system,Important,Pending,Maryland,test@email.com,Contractor,Standard,Annapolis,Req-Routine,N/A,N/A,N/A,1/12/2018,Others,TestofDescription,TestAssignee
```

So far I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use Text::CSV_XS;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get CSV file";

my @rows; # array that will store csv values


my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ( { binary => 1 } ) or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

# open file
open my $FH, "<:encoding(utf8)", "$file" or die "$file: $!";

# Skip Header row
<$FH> for 0;

# read file in while loop

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $FH ) ) {        
    {
        push @rows, $row;
    }
}

$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();

# close file
close $FH;
```

Which returns:

```
     Patch system Important Pending Maryland test@email.com Contractor Standard Annapolis Req-Routine N/A N/A N/A 1/12/2018 Others TestofDescription TestAssignee
```

When this is done, each array element is the line with the data in it. I am at a point where I need to parse the data in the entry into variables, but I cannot grasp the necessary context/syntax to perform this. As the fields are going to have string entries, I need to parse in the data in a way that it isnt treated as a new entry. "Patch System" needs to stay together, as an example.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It's the worst possible start to comment out `use strict` and `use warnings`. If you won't take the advice that those options give you then why should we offer more?

Comment: The code you show doesn't print or "return" anything. What do you mean when you say that it does?

Comment: Currently, I am not returning anything, I just need to assign the elements to variables for each row in the CSV.

Use strict and warnings are not commented out, that is a typo. Edited to reflect.

Comment: There's no point in calling `$csv->error_diag` and discarding any return value.

Comment: @TylerKing What do you think `my $row = $csv->getline($FH)` is doing?

Comment: `<$FH> for 0;` is a weird way of writing `<$FH>;`, but it should be `$csv->getline( $FH );`.

Comment: An entirely different approach is to use SQL, with [DBD::CSV](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihxq6rhu7YAhUQ26QKHaKqA-kQFggnMAA&url=http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3A%3ACSV). See e.g. [this script, which I use to query CSV files](https://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/laquso-bin/csvsql).

Comment: Okay, what are you doing to see the text you have shown after `Which returns`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking for

my ($short_desc, $priority, $status, ...) = @$row;

But that makes a needless assumption about the order of the fields.

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

@ARGV == 1
    or die("usage\n");

my ($qfn) = @ARGV;

open(my $FH, "<:encoding(utf8)", $qfn)
    or die("Can't open input file \"$qfn\": $!\n");

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ auto_diag => 2, binary => 1 });

$csv->header($fh);    

while ( my $row = $csv->getline_hr($FH) ) {
    my (
        $short_desc,
        $priority,
        $status,
        ...
    ) = @$row{qw(
        Short_Description
        Priority
        Status
        ...
    )};

    ...
}
```